# How to check/limit a sqlite database size efficiently?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt

I would like to check the size of a SQLite database and if it is too big, it will notify the user to stop insert data into it.

But how could I check the total number of rows, or the file size of the database efficiently? It is good to have some O(1) method so that I could check for every insertion the user submitted.

I am working on Qt mainly for Windows.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `select count(*) from [table]` is optimized into something constant time instead of actually traversing all the rows. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Keep in mind that SQLite databases will generally grow without bounds unless you're careful to vacuum them now and then: http://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply check the size of the database file and associated journal. That would be O(1) since the number of system calls will always be the same. Something like this:

```
if (QFileInfo(dbFilePath).size() + QFileInfo(dbFilePath + "-journal").size() > maxSize) {
   // Prevent insertion
}
```

Comment: Sorry but what is this "-journal" part?

Comment: @Nyaruko, SQLite creates a journal file next to the database file to store the transactions. The name of this file is simply the name of the db file + "-journal" appended at the end. So if your file is mydb.sqlite, the journal will be mydb.sqlite-journal